# How to put a border around the whole cell?

Tags: html, css, border

I want that the "innerborder" is around the whole cell, if focused. Right now its just around the length of the word. 
I want that the border goes around the whole cell.
Which is the  code sniped which I should add ?

```
td:focus{
    border: 2px inset white;
    border-width:2px;
    content: '';
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code also in a jsFiddle!

Comment: Just a side note. If you use `border: 2px inset white`, isn't the `border-width:2px` obsolete? Since you already defined it before.

Comment: What do you mean by “innerborder”?

Comment: I mean with "innerborder" the border which is inside of the cell:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l914itjvub7v1vy/jvRcshM5lk#lh:null-cell.JPG

Answer (score 1):

It's highlighting the "length of the word" because you're resetting the cell's height and width (ultimately resetting it to the length of its content). To fix this, simply remove `width: auto` and `height: auto`:

```css
td:focus{
    border: 2px inset white;
    border-width:2px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/pLr8z/).

Comment: If i use your solution I get this one:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l914itjvub7v1vy/jvRcshM5lk#lh:null-cell2.JPG

Comment: You'd have to post up more of your code for us to see why that's happening. It's probably caused by the absolute positioning - why are you doing that?

Comment: Without this element the "innerborder" looks different

Comment: Sorry. I thought this would do it, but the little grey border on top and left side goes away if i would delete absolute positioning..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxypyaafc3bm9d9/cell3.JPG?m

Comment: @user2889693 that's a separate question to what you've initially asked. You'll need to post up your HTML and CSS so that we can reproduce this issue (ideally using something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)).